# Create tidy data in R with time stamps based on time stap "size"

Tags: r

I am conducting an analysis on the cycle time variations for each of our processes related to the different products we produce. Our SAP data contains Start and Finish log entries of the worker and the objective is to calculate the cycle times with this info.

However, SAP exports the start and finish time stamps in one column and there is no reference column available stating what is the start and what is the finish time. This makes tidying up the data with e.g. spread not possible.

**Current Data**

- 1.6 million rows
- 150 Operations
- 10 thousand orders

. A small sample of the data looks like this.

```
Order <-  rep(c(1059866,1059891),each = 4)
Operation <- rep(c(1510,1550),4)
Timestamp <- c("30-11-2016 07:33:30", "30-11-2016 07:33:42", "30-11-2016 16:00:13", "30-11-2016 16:00:18", "30-11-2016 07:35:21", "30-11-2016 07:35:43", "30-11-2016 16:00:43", "30-11-2016 16:00:39")

df_current <- cbind(Order, Operation, Timestamp)
```

This start and finish info is required for every process step ("Operation").
Logically the earliest timestamp is the start log entry and the latest timestamp is finish log entry.

However I can't figure out how to tell R to create a new column that correctly indicates which time stamp is start and finish based on the Timestamp.

**Desired Data**

```
Order <-  rep(c(1059866,1059891),each = 4)
Operation <- rep(c(1510,1550),4)
Timestamp <- c("30-11-2016 07:33:30", "30-11-2016 07:33:42", "30-11-2016 16:00:13", "30-11-2016 16:00:18", "30-11-2016 07:35:21", "30-11-2016 07:35:43", "30-11-2016 16:00:43", "30-11-2016 16:00:39")
Status <- c("Start" , "Finish", "Start" , "Finish", "Start" , "Finish",  "Finish", "Start")   

df_desired <- cbind(Order, Operation, Timestamp, Status)
```

When the data look like that I can easily tidy up the data.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you can transform your data to `data.frame` instead of `matrix`:

```
df_current <- data.frame(Order, Operation, Timestamp)

df.With.Status <- do.call(rbind, #rbind the dataframes to a big dataframe
lapply(split(df_current,list(df_current$Order,df_current$Operation)), #split dataframe by unique order/operation combinations and apply function for each combination
       function(df){
         df$Timestamp <- strptime(rev(as.character(df$Timestamp)),format="%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S") #Convert to Time, so that it is sortable
         df <- df[order(df$Timestamp),] # rearrange the dataframe in case of wrong order
         df$Status <- c("Start","Finish") #add status
         return(df)
       }))
```

Comment: Uni Jena.. Nice, da war ich auch.

Comment: Thank you very much for your input Julian! The code does exactly what I had in mind. I have already analysed my first batch of the data with success thanks to your code. :)  cheers!

Answer (score 1):

with `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)


  df_current %>% as.data.frame() %>%
    group_by(Operation, Order) %>%
    mutate(Timestamp = as.POSIXct(Timestamp, format = "%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S"),
           Status = case_when(Timestamp == min(Timestamp) ~ "Start",
                              TRUE ~ "Finish")) %>%
    arrange(Order, Operation)


# A tibble: 8 x 4
# Groups:   Operation, Order [4]
  Order   Operation Timestamp           Status
  <fct>   <fct>     <dttm>              <chr> 
1 1059866 1510      2016-11-30 07:33:30 Start 
2 1059866 1510      2016-11-30 16:00:13 Finish
3 1059866 1550      2016-11-30 07:33:42 Start 
4 1059866 1550      2016-11-30 16:00:18 Finish
5 1059891 1510      2016-11-30 07:35:21 Start 
6 1059891 1510      2016-11-30 16:00:43 Finish
7 1059891 1550      2016-11-30 07:35:43 Start 
8 1059891 1550      2016-11-30 16:00:39 Finish
```

also, since your data is quite big: `data.table`

```
library(data.table)

dfc_2 <- as.data.frame(df_current)

dfc_2$Timestamp <- as.POSIXct(Timestamp, format = "%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S")

setDT(df_curr)[, Status := ifelse(Timestamp == min(Timestamp), "Start", "Finish"),
               keyby = .(Operation, Order)]
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your amazing response speed and code. I like the conditional approach in the code but for some reason I can't get it to work... The result I get  in the column status is "Start" on the first line and all the others "Finish". I have not figured out what I am doing wrong yet but I am still puzzling. :)